# Java Parentheses Flip in String

Tags: java, string

How can I do a replace on a string so that "(" becomes ")" and ")" becomes "("?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be tempting to use `.replace()` but if you replace `)` with `(` and then `(` with `)` you'll end up with all `)`. Instead, iterate over the string and use a stringbuilder to build your string.

```
String swapParens(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.ensureCapacity(s.length()); // preallocate to prevent resizing
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch(c) {
            case ')': sb.append('('); break;
            case '(': sb.append(')'); break;
            default: sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

I'm aware you could put something in there as a placeholder to swap against, but if it already existed in your string, you'd have a big problem.

Consider using "xxx" as your swap string. If your string was "abcx(yz)", and you replace ( with xxx, you end up with "abcxxxyz)" Then you replace ) with ( so you have "abcxxxxyz(". Then you replace xxx with ) so you have "abc)xyz(". Certainly not cool!

Comment: This is certainly the most correct method. Actually, it may be the most efficient way too as the string is copied only once.

Comment: I like your example showing that even a `xxx` not contained in the original string may cause troubles.

Comment: I'd only suggested to add capacity to the StringBulder ctor to avoid reallocations: StringBuilder(s.length()) (UPDATE: was added)

Comment: @road Judging by the timestamps, it was added before your comment even **:-)** I will confess that your comment about efficiency inspired me to realize the string is indeed copied more than once when you consider the StringBuilder reallocation.

Comment: I do not claim the ownership :) especially since you preferred ensureCapacity() to constructor().

Comment: Wouldn't my approach with getting the `char` array be more efficient? It has way, way fewer function calls, and doesn't create a list data structure or anything.

Comment: @Claudiu It may be, that's why I personally upvoted it too. Or may be not, as StringBuilder with pre-allocation capacity is essentially working with a char array too. A test is required to tell.

Comment: @Claudui The order of efficiency is the same. The function calls will be inlined by the JVM, and the code is, in my opinion, cleaner. I think your solution is 100% viable as well. At that point it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
text.replace("(", "xxx").replace(")", "(").replace("xxx",")")
```

where `xxx` is something that certainly doesn't occur in your string.

Comment: How can you guarantee a particular substring will never occur though?

Comment: Well, one can virtually guarantee that the expected time when a specific long substring will appear in the particular type of texts is sometime after the death of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

You can first replace `"("` with an unused char, then `")"` with `"("`, then that unused char with `")"`:

```
String swapParens(String s) {
    return s.replace('(', '\0').replace(')', '(').replace('\0', ')');
}
```

If you already have a null character in the string, though, that won't work, so it's not a good general solution.

Otherwise you can use [glowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696567/java-parentheses-flip-in-string/5696585#5696585)'s approach, but what might be more efficient is getting the bytes into an array and replacing them yourself, then re-building the string:

```
String swapParens(String s) {
    char[] bytes = s.toCharArray():
    for (int i=0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i]=='(') bytes[i] = ')';
        else if (bytes[i]==')') bytes[i] = '(';
    }
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(text);
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
   if(str.charAt(i)=='(') srt.setCharAt(i,')');
   else if(str.charAt(i)==')') str.setCharAt(i,'(');
}
text = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a character you would never ever find in the string of text, you can use `.replace(')', 'unusedChar').replace('(', ')').replace('unusedChar', '(');`